# Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, html, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.5

I try to realize a web interface, where you can upload xml files, which are later on analyzed to create a Database from them. I am using play framework 2.5.x

So I'm getting my file via upload:

```html
    <form action="target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="xml" accept="text/xml"/> 
      <button type="submit"> Los! </input>
    </form>
```

In my controller I'm getting the file from the request and then try to parse it into a Document variable (org.w3c.dom.Document) like this:

```
MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart<File> part = body.getFile("xml");
        File f = part.getFile();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = dBuilder.parse(f);
```

Even if the XML file I'm trying to upload has

```
encoding="UTF-8"
```

set, I'm getting the error message:

```
Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Has anyone an Idea why this is and how i could resolve this (or if my approach is stupid at all)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure that the file is actually saved in UTF-8?

Comment: Good point. Just re-checked it in Notepad++, but it was UTF-8 already :(

Comment: Perhaps it includes a BOM? Windows allows that in UTF-8 but the standards don't.